# How to add toggle on javascript and jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code below that show and hide certain form when click but Im sure there's a better way to do it. It will change the icon after clicking the icon. How can I add toggle to it so it will be on just one block of code.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.bi-arrows-angle-contract', function() {
        $('#fupForm').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('bi-arrows-angle-contract').addClass('bi-arrows-angle-expand');
    })

    $(document).on('click', '.bi-arrows-angle-expand', function() {
        $('#fupForm').slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass('bi-arrows-angle-expand').addClass('bi-arrows-angle-contract');
    })
```

Comment: You could probably do it in one function but it would require a bunch of `if () ...` tests to determine what action to take, and that would make it more complicated that it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element which is clicked has `bi-arrows-angle-contract` class or not depending on this remove/add your classes .So , your code will look like below :

```
$(document).on('click', '.bi-arrows-angle-contract,.bi-arrows-angle-expand', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("bi-arrows-angle-contract")) {
    $('#fupForm').slideUp()
    $(this).removeClass('bi-arrows-angle-contract').addClass('bi-arrows-angle-expand');
  } else {
    $('#fupForm').slideDown()
    $(this).removeClass('bi-arrows-angle-expand').addClass('bi-arrows-angle-contract');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do would be to change your CSS so that you don't need two separate classes for the same element, but just a single class, which may or may not be present. Eg, instead of

```
.bi-arrows-angle-contract {
  /* rules */
}
.bi-arrows-angle-expand {
  /* rules */
}
```

have

```
.bi-arrows-angle {
  /* rules */
}
.bi-arrows-angle.expand {
  /* rules */
}
```

where `.bi-arrows-angle` matches the element.

Then all you need to do is toggle `expand` on and off.

```
let expanded = false;
$('.bi-arrows-angle').on('click', function() {
    $('#fupForm')[expanded ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
    $(this).toggleClass('expand');
    expanded = !expanded;
})
```

You could also use [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) and avoid the outside variable.

```
$('.bi-arrows-angle').on('click', function () {
    const expanded = $(this).hasClass('expand');
    $('#fupForm')[expanded ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
    $(this).toggleClass('expand');
})
```